# Laravel5 .How to store a variable in the database and then display it with its value on the page

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

I have a variable `$title` that I want to save in the database. 
I need to display it with its value on the page using Laravel5.

my code is:

`{!! $article->title  !!}`

that gives me the following data on the page : `$title` , instead I want to see the value of the variable.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Make sure your view file has the extension `.blade.php` so it gets compiled by the Blade template engine.

Comment: Make sure that `$article->title` is a valid column in your DB and you are using the correct model.

Comment: title is a valid column n the database and it shows me the value from it, the thing is that I want to display the variable value instead of variable itself.

Comment: title is a valid column in the database, the thing is that I want to display the variable value instead of the variable itself.

I have $title = "Title Name";
if I have this code in article.blade.php 

{{ $title }} ----> displays Title Name on the page.

That is what I want to achieve, but I need to store $title in the database.
I have column title where I store this: "$title";

Then, I retrieve data from database: 

{!! $article->title  !!} -----> displays $title, instead of Title Name

Comment: Are you  sure that the actual value of variable $title isn't "$title"?

Comment: yes, because it displays the correct value, when I display variable not from the database. The $title renders as a text when it comes from the database.

Comment: Are you passing $article to your view correctly? Or, does your view have access to the $article object?

Comment: Please show, how you pass your data to a view?
Also, please do <?php echo var_dump($article); ?> in the blade template, not the controller.

Answer (score 0):

to output it on blade:

```
{{ $article->title }}
```

Comment: This works for laravel 4. The question is on laravel 5.

Comment: Both `{{...}}` and `{!!...!!}` are valid delimiters in Blade (for Laravel 4 and 5), the only difference is the second one doesn't escape the output, so the OPs delimiter use is not the problem.

Comment: this works on L5, but i need to see the query. its a collection an array what is is type?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have the right value in the database? Because {!! $article->title !!} don't make much more than convert it into

```
<?php echo $article->title ?>
```

so if you get $title as output, my assumption is that you store that in some way as value to the db.

you also can execute normal php in blade, so try to

```
<?php var_dump($article)?>
```

or

```
<?php var_dump($article->title)?>
```

to check what you really receive.

Answer (score -1):

Output in laravel 5 blade:

```
{{ $article->title }}
```

Comment: _Always_ escape data coming from the database. This will print the raw value. You should use the `{{` `}}` delimiters instead.